# libgdx json serializer with a custom reader but default writer?

Tags: java, json, libgdx, serialization

I'd like to achieve the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036975/how-to-implement-libgdx-json-serializable-with-default-reader-and-custom-writer) question.

I need to use a custom reader as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786193/parsing-json-into-a-nested-arraylist-in-libgdx), however, The default writer will work fine. Is there a way I can fire default writing logic from within the overridden write method?

The problem I'm having is whatever I try calls my custom writer which obviously leads to a loop and a stack overflow error.

```
@Override
public void write(Json json) {
    // ?? HELP!
}

@Override
public void read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData) {
    json.readFields(this, jsonData);
    checkForDodgyHighScores();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you need:

```
@Override
public void write(Json json) {
    json.writeFields(this);
}
```

If you don't want to write some object which creates loops, mark them as transient.

Comment: If I have a custom writer on some fields that are creating loops, then there's a good chance I don't want those fields to be transient.